# why does the partial pressure not change?

Tags: equilibrium, gas-phase-chemistry

Suppose I have the equilibrium in a closed container at constant temperature:

$$\ce{2CaSO4(s) -> 2CaO(s) + 2SO2(g) + O2(g)}$$

If the volume of the container is halved, the reaction should move towards that side having lesser number of gaseous moles and hence the partial pressures of $\ce{O2}$ and $\ce{SO2}$ must change but it is given that they won't change.

How do you solve this question?

Comment: $$ \text{You can use \ce{} to automatically format chemical compounds.}$$ Since the temperature is not said to have been changed, can we assume a change in pressure. is there anyother information given?

Comment: no other information has been given.Thanks for helping out to format chemical compounds

Comment: What is the exact question? Could you specify the source? Currently you have a statement and your attempt. no question to solve :)

Comment: Perhaps they mean that the *ratio* of SO2 and O2 won´t change.

Comment: the source-FIITJEE AITS

Comment: actual question-First this reaction was given and they stated that enthalpy change for this reaction is positive and it occurs at 1600K in a container and they asked to pick the correct options.In one of the options it was given-'If volume of the container is halved,partial pressure of O2 will remain the same" and it was given correct.In another option it was given-"The partial pressure of so2 will change if volume of container is doubled" and it was given as incorrect option

Comment: Of course the pressure won't change; it is determined by the equilibrium alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The given explanations are correct, but there is a slightly different way of looking at it which makes it easier to understand. While

2CaSO4(s)⟶2CaO(s) + 2SO2(g) + O2(g)

is quite a correct way to describe the equilibrium, it is worthwhile to remember that since we have an equilibrium, we probably also have some CaO(s) on the left:

2CaSO4(s) + nCaO(s)⟶2CaO(s) + 2SO2(g) + O2(g).

Then, mentally halving the volume of the container doubles the pressure (mentally), which then causes a back reaction with the CaO on the left side, leaving the partial pressures unchanged because they are dependent on the nature of the equilibrium constant.

Putting the CaO on the left side is like completing the mental picture of a seesaw (a metaphor for equilibrium), which otherwise has a weight on one side and not on the other.

Answer (score 1):

The partial pressures initially increase, when the volume is decreased.

But they return to the original values, when the equilibrium is re-established, implying temperature is kept constant.